# ERROR: column "" of relation "" does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, procedure, relation

I have created a table and trying to perform a simple insert statement. I am getting an error saying ERROR:  column "namespecies" of relation "species" does not exist.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Species (
    nameSpecies             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    scientificName          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    population              BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Species_cc0 PRIMARY KEY (nameSpecies),
    CONSTRAINT Species_cc1 UNIQUE (scientificName),
    CONSTRAINT Species_formatNom CHECK
        (nameSpecies SIMILAR TO '[a-z ]*' AND scientificName SIMILAR TO '[a-z ]*')
);
```

Here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Species (nameSpecies, scientificName, population) VALUES ('cat', 'feline', 600000000);
```

Am I missing something??

Comment: Your code works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=23ef68259453c38bef306a98f5b0e054.

Comment: Perhaps you did not use the exact statement that you show. Could it be, that you quoted the fieldnames in your create table statement? `“nameSpecies“` preserves capitalization `nameSpecies` will be lowercased.

Comment: My guess: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20878932/939860

Comment: Never Ever Use CamelCase In SQL. There Is No Need For And Will Only Generate Issues, No Matter What Brand Of DataBase You Use.